# Compiling swift source files stuck

Tags: swift, xcode8

I have been working on my project when suddenly I have not compiled anymore, it stays waiting in Compile swift source files ... I cleaned the project, the folder, deleted the app and nothing. Is there any way to know what is happening?

Comment: what version of Xcode?

Comment: Close Xcode and run: `rm -frd ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` to clean the DerivedData dir

Comment: @alejandro And if you have big array or dictionary literals, it helps to break them down into smaller literals and assemble them again before usage: the Swift compiler chokes easily on big literals.

Comment: 8.0, 8.1, 8.2, 8.3? a beta? :) Best to give all information in the question

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there any way to know what is happening?

Yes. Go into the *Report Navigator* which is the one selected by the little speech bubble at the top right of the navigator pane. It will give you a list of all the actions you have performed like builds and tests and runs. The current build will be at the top of the pane. Click on it.

In the main editor you will see some buttons at the top and maybe some messages. Click the *All Messages* button and it will show you a tree view of the current build. The bottom line will  be what the build system is doing now. If it is not changing (i.e. new lines appearing) the build is stuck.

Almost certainly the bottom line will be something like `Compile SomeFile.swift`. Assuming it is, you can now triage the problem. The Swift compiler usually gets stuck on inferring types for complicated expressions. The way to triage this is to comment out the entire file and then add lines back until the problem reappears. Make sure that you always add enough back so that the file compiles without error.

Obviously, the last line you added back will be the one causing the problem. Usually it's an expression that concatenates strings together with non strings that causes the problem.

Comment: Hi @JeremyP in my case i do not see any particular file name. How can i identify which file is causing issue?

Comment: @Bista I'm sorry but it would be hard to tell without more context. Maybe you could ask a new question and post your build log.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in dictionary [String:Any] when I change the dictionary to [String:String] the problem is resolved . Is very strange..

Comment: It's probably type inference getting confused.